# postgres - date time is automatically converted

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, visual-studio-code, time

Using vscode in debug mode, when I hover over a date field, it show as the below image.
[image]

but when I logged it out, it get converted to

```
"execution_date":"2021-12-02T20:23:48.322Z"
```

which is minus 7 hour.
The field is stored in postgres database on AWS RDS as timestamp, running `show timezone;` returns UTC and I am using VSCode in GMT+7 time. How can I fix this because the date get changed and used to call api, so the returned result would be incorrect.

Comment: Is the field `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`? Using `psql` what does `show timezone;` return for that server? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the field is timestamp and running `show timezone;` returns UTC. When hover over the execution_date field while debugging, it shows the same date and time as stored in the database, but when it get logged out and used to call API, it get minus 7 hours.

Comment: You have now found out why you should not use `timestamp` if you care about time zones. Read [Date/Datetimes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) 8.5.1.3. Time Stamps. Short version your `datetime` is assumed to be at `UTC` on entry. To get it back to your time: `select '2021-12-02T20:23:48.322Z' at time zone 'ICT'; 2021-12-03 03:23:48.322`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver But when debug why does it show the same time as stored in the database, but when get logged out and used to call an API, it gets minus 7 hours. I think this is something related to my OS or VSCode right?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry don't know why but I can't edit the above reply. In the database it is stored as `2021-12-03 03:23:48.322`, the doc states that `the resulting value is derived from the date/time fields in the input value, and is not adjusted for time zone.`, I am using Sequelize and the query generated doesn't set any timezone so it should't get minus 7 hours, is this correct.

Comment: To simplify for the following do things through `psql`. That will take out one layer out of the equation. So insert a row into the table, the select from that table to see what the value is?  Then run the API and see what you get? Where is the API running and what is the code that deals with the datetime?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you for your help I have found the answer for it and have put it to answer section.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer as that would depend on more information. Instead it is an explanation of what is going on that may help you troubleshoot:

```
set TimeZone = UTC;
show timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
--Show that timestamp is taken at UTC
 select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2021-12-05 18:23:38.604681+00

--Table with timestamp and timestamptz to show different behavior.
create table dt_test(id integer, ts_fld timestamp, tsz_fld timestamptz);

--Insert local time 'ICT'
insert into dt_test values (1, '2021-12-03 03:23:48.322+07', '2021-12-03 03:23:48.322+07');

--The timestamp entry ignores the time zone offset, while the timestamptz uses it to rotate to UTC as '2021-12-03 03:23:48.322+07' is same as '2021-12-02 20:23:48.322+00'
select * from dt_test ;
 id |         ts_fld          |          tsz_fld           
----+-------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | 2021-12-03 03:23:48.322 | 2021-12-02 20:23:48.322+00


--timestamp takes the value as at 'ICT' and then rotates it to the current 'TimeZone' UTC. The timestamptz takes the value at UTC at rotates it to 'ICT'
select ts_fld AT TIME ZONE 'ICT', tsz_fld AT TIME ZONE 'ICT' from dt_test ;
          timezone          |        timezone         
----------------------------+-------------------------
 2021-12-02 20:23:48.322+00 | 2021-12-03 03:23:48.322
```

I am guessing at some point in the process to get the value for the API the code is taking the `timestamp` value and applying `AT TIME ZONE 'ICT'` either in the database or downstream using some equivalent procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it's is related to how Sequelize and postgres deal with `timestamp without timezone`. If you have the same problem like me, please refer to the following link: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3000

Comment: What this points out is that if you care about time zones you should use the `timestamptz` type.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this is actually an already existing system. Thank you I will pay more attention to the timestamp from now.